# Change of Style of plotting 3D plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, normal-distribution

I tried to plot the Bivariate Gaussian Distribution. I got the plane plot for the same on the 3D axes which is shown below.

[image: Bivariate Gaussian Distribution]

However I want a graph which looks like the following

[image: Bivariate Gaussian Distribution]

The code I wrote is the following

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Our 2-dimensional distribution will be over variables X and Y
N = 60
X = np.linspace(-3, 3, N)
Y = np.linspace(-3, 4, N)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

# Mean vector and covariance matrix
mu = np.array([0., 1.])
Sigma = np.array([[ 1. , -0.5], [-0.5,  1.5]])

# Pack X and Y into a single 3-dimensional array
pos = np.empty(X.shape + (2,))
pos[:, :, 0] = X
pos[:, :, 1] = Y

def multivariate_gaussian(pos, mu, Sigma):
    """Return the multivariate Gaussian distribution on array pos.

    pos is an array constructed by packing the meshed arrays of variables
    x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_k into its _last_ dimension.

    """

    n = mu.shape[0]
    Sigma_det = np.linalg.det(Sigma)
    Sigma_inv = np.linalg.inv(Sigma)
    N = np.sqrt((2*np.pi)**n * Sigma_det)
    # This einsum call calculates (x-mu)T.Sigma-1.(x-mu) in a vectorized
    # way across all the input variables.
    fac = np.einsum('...k,kl,...l->...', pos-mu, Sigma_inv, pos-mu)

    return np.exp(-fac / 2) / N

# The distribution on the variables X, Y packed into pos.
Z = multivariate_gaussian(pos, mu, Sigma)

# Create a surface plot and projected filled contour plot under it.
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=3, cstride=3, linewidth=1, antialiased=True,
                cmap=cm.viridis)

cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=-0.15, cmap=cm.viridis)

# Adjust the limits, ticks and view angle
ax.set_zlim(-0.15,0.2)
ax.set_zticks(np.linspace(0,0.2,5))
ax.view_init(27, -21)

plt.show()
```

Please let me know what needs to be changed.

Comment: I have no answer for a 3D representation, but you may have a look at 2D [seaborn `jointplot`s](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html#seaborn.jointplot)

Comment: sure will look into the same